# Add AVD to project Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-virtual-device

Hey I try to add this phone in order to start a project by it does not work.
I tried  almost everything.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Is you system x86 ? otherwise try to install an emulator compatible with x64

Comment: Hey, I have 64 bit. All my options that I see in ABI column are for x86

Comment: you can also use your real time device

Answer (score 1):

it looks like virtualization is disabled in your bios.

Have you tried one of this instructions?

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Activating_the_Intel_VT_Virtualization_Feature

or

https://2nwiki.2n.cz/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75202968

I hope it will work